# List pass through ajax in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass list through AJAX. How can I do this and assign value on runtime. I am doing it, but it pass null value. Here is my code.

**JQuery:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    aabc += { id: i, color: 'Level' + i } + ",";
}
var str2 = aabc.replace(/,$/, " ")
JSONString3 = [str2];
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("test123", "ConfigurableTradeLane")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(JSONString3),
    success: function (data) {
       //alert("success");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('Error message.');
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public void test123(List<TradelaneDetailViewModel> viewmodel)
        {
            //nothing
        }
```

It send ***"item value is null"***. Please help me.

Comment: What id the method you are posting to? (and you need to declare a javascript array and push the objects into it)

Comment: @A.Q, can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `TradelaneDetailViewModel` contains properties `id` and `color`, then the script needs to be

```
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    items.push({ id: i, color: 'Level' + i });
}
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("test123", "ConfigurableTradeLane")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ viewmodel: items }),
    success: function (data) {
       //alert("success");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('Error message.');
    }
});
```